# How To Add Copy To Clipboard Button in Flutter(Dart)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**My Code** 
Here I want Add Functionality To Button OnClick Copy To Clipboard Help Me.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Clipboard"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text("This is a very awesome quote"),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Copy to the clipboard"),
              color: Colors.cyan,
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Paint your app to life in milliseconds with Stateful Hot Reload. Use a rich set of fully-customizable widgets to build native interfaces in minutes.

Answer (score 2):

In the button click add below code for a copy to clipboard.

```
 Clipboard.setData( ClipboardData(text: "Add your text to copy")).then((result){
      // show toast or snackbar after successfully save
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "copied"); 

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below code without adding any plugins & notify the user:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: "Your Copy text")).then((_){
       ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Copied to your clipboard !')));
});
```